# Constant ext4 corruption

Tags: filesystems, ext4, initramfs, corruption, proxmox

For the second time now in about 6 weeks, my Proxmox root has reported ext4 errors and I've had to fix them by booting into initramfs and running fsck.ext4.

There's one file I can't seem to delete - its permissions are messed up, and running lsattr/chattr/chmod/chown/rm fails.

So first, how do you deal with a file that won't delete, and second, why would I be experiencing ongoing corruption like this? The machine is on all the time, there's no issue with clean power, the OS runs on a brand new and reputable SATA SSD (Samsung Evo 870), using all new hardware - an X570 motherboard, Ryzen 7 5700G, 64GB RAM, etc. Nothing jumps out at me from dmesg.

Comment: 1. Kernel, 2. Configuration, 3. Hardware. 1. Check around for known ext4 corruption bugs in whatever kernel you're running. 3. Re-seat all the hardware cards and cables. Run memtest86+ to check the memory. 2. Check you've not overlapped partitions on the disk

Comment: @roaima will do, thanks. Re overlapped partitions - how do I do that? fdisk and get a print of the start/stop for each partition?

Comment: Harv, yes that should work `fdisk -l /dev/sda` etc.